# Powerscript with menu options - prompting for input

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script with the following requirements but I am having trouble getting options 3, 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12 to function properly. Here are the requirements and my current script is listed below. Thank in advance!

Script requirements:

You are to develop a PowerShell script that displays a list of options to the user, prompts for input, and runs the function selected. It can be tricky to find all the right commands and build the menu logic, so you will need all of the allotted time to accomplish this script. Your code MUST contain comments to explain it.

The menu interface should include all of the following requirements:

1. At command file startup, the color should be set to white text on a blue background and the screen should be cleared
2. The menu options should be visible until you exit the script (unless displaying an option)
3. A title for your utility should be displayed
4. The date and time should be displayed at the top of the menu directly after or under the title
5. The screen should be cleared before displaying the menu after commands are run
6. Output that runs more than the length of the command window should be paged with the user prompted to press a key to run the next screen
7. The user should be given time to examine the output of their selection before the menu is redisplayed
   The menu should include the following options:
8. Show System Hostname
9. Show System IP Addresses
10. Show System DNS Servers
11. Show System Default Gateway
12. Show Amount of Memory Available to Run Applications
13. Show PATH environment variable
14. List Drivers Installed on System using Windows command driverquery (Links to an external site.) as the source
15. List current running tasks
16. Kill task
17. Display a text file on the screen
18. Get File Security Information
19. Show All TCP/IP Network Connections and listening Ports
20. You must display a prompt for the user to input an option, such as a process ID or file name.

############Current Script############################
function Show-Menu
{
$console.ForegroundColor = "white"
$console.BackgroundColor = "blue"
cls
param (
[string]$Title = 'User Selection Menu'

```
)
cls
Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
Write-Host "Date and time is: ============= $((Get-Date).ToString())"
Write-Host "1: Press '1' for this option. Show System Hostname"
Write-Host "2: Press '2' for this option. Show System IP address"
Write-Host "3: Press '3' for this option. Show System DNS Servers"
Write-Host "4: Press '4' for this option. Show System Default Gateway"
Write-Host "5: Press '5' for this option. Show Amount of memory available to run applications"
Write-Host "6: Press '6' for this option. Show Path Environment Variables"
Write-Host "7: Press '7' for this option. List Drivers installed in this system"
Write-Host "8: Press '8' for this option. List current running tasks"
Write-Host "9: Press '9' for this option. Kill Task"
Write-Host "10: Press '10' for this option. Display a text file on the screen"
Write-Host "11: Press '11' for this option. Get security file information"
Write-Host "12: Press '12' for this option. Show all TCP/IP connections and listening ports"
Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}
Here is the implementation of show-menu function part

do
{
Show-Menu
$input = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
switch ($input)
{
'1' {
cls
'You chose option #1'
'Computer name or hostname is RIEMERM'
} '2' {
cls
'You chose option #2'
 Get-NetIPAddress | Format-Table
} '3' {
cls
'You chose option #3'
$Zones = @(Get-DnsServerZone)
ForEach ($Zone in $Zones) {
Write-Host "`n$($Zone.ZoneName)" -ForegroundColor "Green"
$Zone | Get-DnsServerResourceRecord
}
}'4' {
cls
'You chose option #4'
Get-NetRoute |
where {$_.DestinationPrefix -eq '0.0.0.0/0'} |
select { $_.NextHop }
} '5' {
cls
'You chose option #5'
'I am not sure how to do this'
}'6' {
cls
'You chose option #6'
# List Paths
$Env:Path
}'7' {
cls
'You chose option #7'
 Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion
}'8' {
cls
'You chose option #8'
$env=Get-Process powershell -FileVersionInfo
}'9' {
cls
'You chose option #9'
$env=Stop-Process -Name "wordpad"
}'10' {
cls
'You chose option #10'
$env=Get-Content contexttext.txt | foreach {Write-Output $_}
}'11' {
cls
'You chose option #11'
$env=Get-Acl C:\ProgramFiles\contexttext.txt
}'12' {
cls
'You chose option #12'
$env=Get-NetTCPConnection
}'q' {
return
}
}
pause
}
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 0):

utility title

```
   $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = “Changed Title”
```

show system host name

```
   $env:computername
```

show system ip name -> which one? ethernet? wireless?

show system dns

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress
```

Show System Default Gateway -> whats the default gateway?